# Angular Material: Browser Crashes When Value Set on MatButtonToggleGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a strange problem that I need help troubleshooting: I wrote an Angular app and added a [MatButtonToggleGroup](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview) to it like this:

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group [value]="'Mix'">
    <mat-button-toggle value="Mix">Mix</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Dip">Dip</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Wipe">Wipe</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="DVE">DVE</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Noop">Noop</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Animated">Anim</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Nothing fancy. Everything hardcoded, static values. Simple. What bothers me at this point is that when I press on of the buttons there's no indication of that value being selected. Anyway ... Now I want `Mix` to be selected when the page is loaded, so I changed it to

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group value="Mix">
    <mat-button-toggle value="Mix">Mix</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Dip">Dip</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Wipe">Wipe</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="DVE">DVE</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Noop">Noop</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="Animated">Anim</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

At that point, the browser renders only parts of the page and is completely stuck. I have to kill the tab. When I do this with Developer Tools enabled and set to Console output, I see no error. Nothing that points me to any problem.

Any ideas what might be going on or how I could find out? I am on Angular 14.2.6 with Material 14.2.5

**EDIT**
By desparately trying different thing, I found out as soon as I move the toggle group out of this loop, it begins to work:

```js
<div *ngFor="let entry of transitions.entries(); let i = index;" class="transition-box" 
    fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" fxLayoutGap="20px"
    fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="start stretch">

    <mat-button-toggle-group>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Mix">Mix</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Dip">Dip</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Wipe">Wipe</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="DVE">DVE</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Noop">Noop</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Animated">Anim</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>

...
```

**EDIT**
I get the same result just by adding this within the loop

```js
<mat-select>
    <mat-option value="Mix">Mix</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Dip">Dip</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Wipe">Wipe</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="DVE">DVE</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Noop">DVE</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Animated">Animated</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Outside the loop: No problem at all.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it is working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cq5x2v?file=src/app/button-toggle-appearance-example.html

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome and tested with Firefox as well. Both show the same behavior.